# Platform Events allow REST API JSON inputs to bypass field Required-ness?

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, api, platform-event

We are finding that when feeding data to a SF Platform Event via the REST API (`/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/My_Pletform_Event__e`), Required field inputs can bypass endpoint validation by supplying an empty string (as JSON e.g.: {"MyRequiredTextField" = ""}) in the payload, or by simply not including the field key in the JSON payload.

This becomes a null for the PE SObject field when accessed in the PE Trigger code (Apex). This same input published to the PE internally (by creating a new My_Pletform_Event__e, populatng the fields, and publishing via Dev Console Anon. Apex tool), draws a REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING exception, as one would expect, never activating the Trigger.

Worse, sending same for a Required NUMERIC field (as JSON: {"MyRequiredNumericField" = ""}), or simply not including the field key in the JSON payload, results in the PE SObject field--when accessed in the PE Trigger code--TO BE NUMERIC ZERO!

This appears to be a corruption of both Type (accepting a non-numeric string value for a numeric field), and Value (a "" input becomes zero in the trigger for numerics, and null for strings).

Can anyone confirm this behavior? I can provide steps to reproduce if needed.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You should raise this to support.